# How Get Magento brand by collection

Tags: magento-1.9

this is my query now i want to get brand from this collection

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('brand')
                ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);
```

Comment: @Sheenu Your answer is for Magento 2, but question is about Magento 1.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get collection by brand then use following code.

```
$attributeSetId=10;
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('brand')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('brand', $attributeSetId);
```

Make ajax call

```
var reloadurl = '". $this->getUrl('adminhtml/test/test') . "ref/' + selectElement.value;
new Ajax.Request(reloadurl, {
                method: 'get',
                onLoading: function (stateform) {
                    $('//yourfieldid').update('Searching...');
                },
                onComplete: function(stateform) {
                    $('yourfieldid').update(stateform.responseText);
                }
            });
```

Comment: $selectField = $fieldset->addField('attribute_set_id', 'select', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('warranty')->__('Select Type'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('warranty')->__('Select Type'),
            'name' => 'warranty[attribute_set_id]',
            'required' => true,
            'options' => $attributeSets,
            'onchange' => 'onchangeStyleShow()',
        )); i create this button and i want to pass the value of this button onchange in php function which is also here in this file how i can do this

Comment: `'onchange' => 'onchangeStyleShow(this.value)'` this will pass value to function.   or use prototype `$('//youridhere).getValue()`

Comment: how pass in php

Comment: hpw pass in php funciton

Comment: @safra can you give me complete information  what are you trying to do?

Comment: i have to select box fields in one select box i am show attribute set and other select box i am showing brands now i have create  function in php which bring brands according to attribute set id now i want that if some body change attribute so the brand change accordingly

Comment: $selectField = $fieldset->addField('attribute_set_id', 'select', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('warranty')->__('Select Type'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('warranty')->__('Select Type'),
            'name' => 'warranty[attribute_set_id]',
            'required' => true,
            'options' => $attributeSets,
            'onchange' => 'onchangeStyleShow(this.value)',
        ));

Comment: $selectField->setAfterElementHtml('
                        <script>
                        function onchangeStyleShow(){
                        alert("test");
                        var attributesetid=document.getElementById("attribute_set_id").value;
                       alert(attributesetid);
                       }
                        </script>
                    ');

Comment: now i want to pass the value here in this function

Comment: public function OptionArray() {

        $attrSetName = 'Mobile Phones';
        //load attribute set id
        $attributeSetId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
                ->load($attrSetName, 'attribute_set_name')
                ->getAttributeSetId();
        //load product collection filter by attribute set id
        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('brand')
                ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);

Comment: @safra you have to use ajax for that to reloading the brands  i added the code how to make simple ajax call

Comment: where is code ?

Comment: @safra in my answer use that to get update data